# Membership provider class

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to know how I can implement membership provider class to have ability to remember users who signed in.

I have Membership provider class and I need functionality of "Remember Me" checkbox but I don't know how I can implement some methods

Comment: It is a little unclear what you mean - what is the issue here? Writing a membership provider? Or logging access?

Comment: I think he means he needs the functionality of "Remember Me" checkbox on the sign-in screen.

Comment: No I Mean writing membership provider

Comment: Yes exactly I need functionality of "Remember Me" but how ?

Comment: How I can implement class to use this functionality

Comment: Sorry Kami, I don't know the answer right now as I haven't done this recently. I just wanted to help for comprehending your question. Hopefully someone will answer you in a few minutes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to implement this functionality you must create a persistent cookie with some expiration date on the users computer. So if the user checks the *Remember me* checkbox you issue the following cookie:

```
var cookie = new HttpCookie("_some_cookie_name_", "username") 
{
    Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(15) // Remember user for 15 days
};
Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
```

And then upon showing the login screen you could check if the cookie is present and prefill the username:

```
var cookie = Request.Cookies["_some_cookie_name_"];
if (cookie != null)
{
    usernameTextBox.Text = cookie.Value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a Hashtable if it's in C#, keyed by the user id.  Something like this (where lsdfjk is just whatever string the user ID corresponds to, and assuming that there is a class UserInfo defined, with a constructor taking string userID as an argument):

```
        string userID = "lsdfjk";
        UserInfo userInfo = null;
        Hashtable htMembers = new Hashtable();
        if (htMembers.ContainsKey(userID))
        {
            userInfo = (UserInfo)htMembers[userID];
        }
        else
        {
            //It's a new member
            userInfo = new UserInfo(userID);
        }
```

Comment: Why not use the strongly typed `Dictionary` class? I see way too many people using `ArrayList` and `Hashtable`.

Answer (score 0):

"Remember Me" doesn't have anything to do with a Membership Provider really.  Basically it is just a function of Forms Authentication, where you set a persistent cookie so that when people show up at the website, it can log them in automatically.

You can do this automatically using the RedirectFromLoginPage() method.

```
FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(username, true);
```

The second parameter, "true", means "set a persistent cookie".  The user will be logged in until the cookie expires or they clear their cookies.

If you need more control over it, you can manually set a cookie by manipulating the cookies collection directly.